# Why is RestSharp AddHeader("Accept", "application/json"); = to a list of item?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, restsharp

I've got this Windows Phone 8 project in C#, where I'm using RestSharp 104.4.0 to make a request to a server. The server only accepts a "Accept" type of "application/json". My code to call the request:

```
var client = new RestClient(_jsonBaseUrl + someURL)
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(someUsername, somePassword)
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = utf8.GetBytes(json);
json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddBody(json);
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

client.ExecuteAsync<UserAccount>(request, response =>
{
    if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Error)
    {
        failure(response.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        success("done");
    }
});
```

the "json" variable is a JSON string.

As you can see i've set my accept type to AddHeader("Accept", "application/json"); But for some wired reason the server receives this as accept type:
"Accept": "application/json, application/xml, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, text/xml"

What do i have to do, to make sure the only accept type the server gets is "Accept": "application/json"?

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restsharp/KD2lsaTC0eM:

> The Accept header is automatically generated by inspecting the
>   "handlers" that are registered with the RestClient instance. One optin
>   is to use RestClient.ClearHandlers (); and then add back explicitly
>   the JSON deserializer with RestClient.AddHandler("application/json",
>   new JsonDeserializer ());

Comment: Have no idea why i couldn't find that with all my Google searches:) but thanks ill give it a shot.

Comment: It was practically the first result :D

Comment: it works, RestClient.ClearHandlers (); then RestClient.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer ()); then delete request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");